# Mails Delays sometimes not received

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7, bluehost

I sent mails using contact form 7 on wordpress. when the mails are sent,sometimes I don't even get the mail.sometimes it delays and sometimes i received. again I got mails with using same mail again and again. but with another mail id I don't receive that mail. 
I use bluehost hosting. and domain email.

where is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: i too have the same problem .. any leads